# New to UBUNTU, problems installing steam

Tags: package-management, dependencies, steam

- Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
- Description:  Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- Release:  14.04
- Codename: trusty

firefox

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for gbs2: 
..........................................................................................................
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that yo have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but     it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libgl1-mesa-glx unity-control-center
```

then do whatever Steam thing you needed to do.

Also, please tell me if it doesn't work, and provide the following information in that case:

1. 64bit or 32bit?
2. Basic hardware information?
3. Anything else that might be helpful?

Comment: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU B940 @ 2.00GHz × 2 
Intel® Sandybridge Mobile

Comment: its a 64bit machine